# C++ pass vector (lvalue to rvalue)

Tags: c++, vector, rvalue, lvalue, lvalue-to-rvalue

Lets say you have 2 `vectors` passed to a function as `lvalue references`. Later you realize, you can use recursion and pass slices of these `vectors` using their `iterators`. 
 
Would it be an appropriate strategy if I go ahead and write some `util` function to use these `vecotrs` as `rvalues` ? Or I should avoid this in any way?

**Simplified pattern:**

```
Node* util(vector<int>&& a, vector<int>&& b) {
    Node* root = new Node(a[0]);

    root->left = util({ a.begin(), a.end() }, { b.begin(), b.end() });
    root->right = util({ a.begin(), a.end() }, { b.begin(), b.end() });

    return root;
}

Node* main(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b) {
    return util({ a.begin(), a.end() }, { b.begin(), b.end() });
}
```

**Realistic example** ([LeetCode 105](https://leetcode.com/problems/construct-binary-tree-from-preorder-and-inorder-traversal/)):

```
TreeNode* util(vector<int>&& preorder, vector<int>&& inorder) {
    if (!preorder.empty()) {
        TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(preorder[0]);

        auto r = find(inorder.begin(), inorder.end(), preorder[0]);

        root->left = util(
        { preorder.begin() + 1, preorder.begin() + 1 + distance(inorder.begin(), r) },
        { inorder.begin(), r });
        root->right = util(
        { preorder.begin() + 1 + distance(inorder.begin(), r), preorder.end() },
        { r + 1, inorder.end() });

        return root;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

TreeNode* buildTree(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder) {
    return util({ preorder.begin(), preorder.end() }, 
                { inorder.begin(), inorder.end() });
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you'd need r-value references (do you want to *move* any data???), ordinary references should be fine, too. As you don't seem to modify input vectors, const references would be appropriate.

Comment: Doesn't this construct a whole new vector for each argument anyway? rvalues wouldn't stop that from happening

Comment: I can't pass vector iterators with ordinary references. This syntax  `root->left = util({ a.begin(), a.end() }, { b.begin(), b.end() });` won't work

Comment: @TharwenWas just about to modify my previous comment in that direction, too... Yes, we're creating copies over copies without ever modifying them. So: const references as in my previous comment, and just call recursively `util(preorder, inorder);` should be absolutely fine.

Comment: @user2376997 You can pass iterators by value; under the hoods, you are more or less just passing pointers into the data anyway... Provide for iterators as arguments to your util function and you can do so. `{a.begin(), a.end()}` is equivalent to `std::vector<int>(a.begin(), a.end())`, i. e. calls the constructor accepting two iterators, which *copies* all data in between these two iterators, i. e. the whole vector in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the wrong way: `{a.begin(), a.end()}` is equivalent to `std::vector<int>(a.begin(), a.end())`, i. e. calls the constructor accepting two iterators, which *copies* all data in between these two iterators, i. e. the whole vector in your case (or sub-ranges of the vector in your more realistic example).

But you don't modify the vectors in any way, so no need for any copies.

If you just want to *read* the original vector, then you can work directly with iterators; you can pass these by value, unter the hoods, they are more or less just pointers into the vector's data anyway:

```
TreeNode* util
(
    vector<int>::const_iterator preorderBegin, vector<int>::const_iterator preorderEnd,
    vector<int>::const_iterator inorderBegin, vector<int>::const_iterator inorderEnd
)
{
    // ...
    ++preorderBegin; // if we do so before the call, we have just one addition; compiler
                     // might optimize to the same code, but we don't rely on it this way
    util(preorderBegin, preorderBegin + distance(), inorderBegin, r);
    // ...
}
```

`const_iterator`? Well, we want to accept `const` vectors:

```
TreeNode* buildTree(vector<int> const& preorder, vector<int> const& inorder)
//                                ^                            ^
// you don't modify the vectors, so accept them as constant
{
    return util(preorder.begin(), preorder.end(), inorder.begin(), inorder.end());
    // note the dropped braces...
}
```